# spring boot dependency issue with plexus-utils library

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

It seems one of the library used by spring boot starter plexus-util have started breaking. I am getting unauthorised error for same. I am using spring boot version 2.1. As I can check in repo there are few recent changes. Someone seems to have added requirement of authorisation for the library. Have any one faced similar problem? Is there any alternative way like including jar for dependency directly? Or using an alternative repo for spring boot.
I am using gradle here for dependencies.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'commerce-tagging-service'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download plexus-utils-2.1.jar (org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

Gradle dependency for spring boot

```
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the Spring repositories for resolving those dependencies. The policy of those repos have changed see https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/29/notice-of-permissions-changes-to-repo-spring-io-fall-and-winter-2020. So use your regular maven central etc. instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply this to build files:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kategory/maven' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

````
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            </repository>```
 Adding the central repos to your maven settings.xml , should work.
````